# how to define varaible and get multiple value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a problem for define variable when i want to get multiple values for example

```
SET @ T_id IN (1,2,10);
```

but it is incorrect!
how can I define it?

```
SELECT * FROM table_T WHERE T_id=@T_id;
```

Instead i write a query for:

```
SELECT * FROM table_T WHERE T_id IN (1,2,10);
```

**But I do not want this style for it .Just I want to define a variable but include multiple values**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET`.

First define your variable like this: `SET @T_id := '1,2,10';`

Then you can do such a query:

```
SELECT T_id FROM table_T WHERE FIND_IN_SET(T_id,@T_id) > 0;
```

See an example based on your description here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fc2ff9e4ac3787d75f829aa7697a8082)

By the way, I recommend to provide a better name for your variable because it's very similar to the column name which makes it bad to read.

Comment: Thank you a lot .in fact it does not work.... we have two table and join together for example:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customer C 
INNER JOIN Devices D ON C.id=D.c_id
WHERE D.OLT IN (1,2,5) and DATE(C.Date)=SUBDATE(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1DAY);

I want define for each condition:
SET @Date=SUBDATE(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY);
SET @olti=(1,2,5);  -- it does not support Multiple Value.
Can you help me? i appreciated...